# static methods and variables in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, static-methods

I want to be able to save a class instance to a private/public static variable, but I can't figure out how to do this in Kotlin.

```
public class Foo {
    private static Foo instance;

    public Foo() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;
        }
    }
    
    public static Foo get() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to create a singleton, check out https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

**Update**: Anyone (like OP) who just needs a so-called "Singleton", sometimes called "Service" (except in Android), should simply use Kotlin's built-in:

```kotlin
object Foo {
    // Done, this already does what OP needed,
    // because the boilerplate codes (like static field and constructor),
    // are taken care of by Kotlin.
}
```

<sup>(Like [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051598/roman-elizarov) rightly pointed out in the comment-section.)</sup>

Previous answer; If you have (or plan to have) multiple `static` variables, then continue reading:

The closest thing to Java's static fields is a companion object. You can find the documentation reference for them here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects

Your code in Kotlin would look something like this:

```
class Foo {

    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: Foo

        fun get(): Foo {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    init {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this
        }
    }

}
```

If you want your fields/methods to be exposed as static to Java callers, you can apply the [`@JvmStatic`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/) annotation:

```
class Foo {

    companion object {
        private lateinit var instance: Foo

        @JvmStatic fun get(): Foo {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    init {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this
        }
    }

}
```

> **Note** that `@JvmStatic` does not need any import (as it's built-in feature of Kotlin).

Comment: If you want to use it like a `static final` field in Java without getters, you probably should mark it `@JvmField`

Answer (score 71):

It looks that you want to define a singleton object. It is supported in Kotlin as a first-class concept:

```
object Foo {
  ... 
}
```

All the boilerplate code with static field and constructor is taken care by the Kotlin automatically. You don't have to write any of that.

From the Kotlin code you can refer to the instance of this object simply as `Foo`. From the Java code you can referer to the instance of this object as `Foo.INSTANCE`, because the Kotlin compiler automatically creates the corresponding static field named `INSTANCE`.

Comment: This is the much better solution, however, for my use case I needed a class because it needed to be able to be created by a Java class loader.

Comment: An object is accessible throughout the entire project though, couldn't that hinder performance?

Answer (score 20):

first you create a simple class then after create a block followed by companion object keyword

for example:

```
class Test{

    companion object{

        fun  getValue(): String{

           return "Test String"

        }
    }
}
```

you can call this class function using class name dot function name

for example:

```
// here you will get the function value
Test.getValue()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a companion object for the class, and if you want the field to be `static` you can use the annotation @JvmStatic. Companion object have access to private members of the class it is companion for.

See below an example:

```
class User {
    private lateinit var name: String

    override fun toString() = name

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val instance by lazy {
            User().apply { name = "jtonic" }
        }
    }
}

class CompanionTest {

    @Test
    fun `test companion object`() {
        User.instance.toString() shouldBe "jtonic"
    }
}
```