# Kotlin: How to access field from another class?

Tags: android, android-studio, variables, kotlin, access-modifiers

```
package example

class Apple {
    val APPLE_SIZE_KEY: String = "APPLE_SIZE_KEY"
}
```

Class:

```
package example

class Store {
     fun buy() {
      val SIZE = Apple.APPLE_SIZE_KEY
    }
}
```

Error:

> 'APPLE_SIZE_KEY' has private access in 'example.Apple'

But [official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#classes-and-interfaces) describes that if we do not specify any visibility modifier, `public` is used by default.

Why is above error coming?

Comment: more on static variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857824/kotlin-static-methods-and-variables/43857895

Comment: please mark an answer as your solution

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you are trying to do is accessing a value of a class that has no instance. Here are three solutions:

```
package example

object Apple {
    val APPLE_SIZE_KEY: String = "APPLE_SIZE_KEY"
}
```

This way you do not need to instantiate anything because of the way `object`s work in Kotlin.

You could also just instantiate your class like this:

```
package example

class Store {
     fun buy() {
      val SIZE = Apple().APPLE_SIZE_KEY
    }
}
```

In this solution you also have an object of `Apple`, but `Apple` is still declared as a class.

The third option is a companion object, which behaves like static variables in Java.

```
package example

class Apple {
    companion object {
        val APPLE_SIZE_KEY: String = "APPLE_SIZE_KEY"
    }
}
```

Comment: It may help to mention `@JvmStatic` which would enable normal static access (`Apple.APPLE_SIZE_KEY`) from Java code, as opposed to `Apple.Companion.INSTANCE.APPLY_SIZE_KEY`.

Answer (score 9):

If you want this to be a class level property instead of an instance level property, you can use a [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects):

```
class Apple {
    companion object {
        val APPLE_SIZE_KEY: String = "APPLE_SIZE_KEY"
    }
}

fun useAppleKey() {
    println(Apple.APPLE_SIZE_KEY)
}
```

What you currently have is an instance property, which you could use like this:

```
fun useInstanceProperty() {
    val apple = Apple()
    println(apple.APPLE_SIZE_KEY)
}
```

Comment: `const val` could be used since the type is `String`, which avoids generating an unnecessary getter. And of course the type can be inferred by the compiler, so: `const val APPLE_SIZE_KEY = "APPLE_SIZE_KEY"`