# Kotlin - How to use a class property in a companion object

Tags: kotlin

I was wondering if I can use a property of a class inside a companion object. for example take the instance bellow:

```
class Person1(val name: String, var age: Int){
    lateinit var surname: String
    companion object myc{
        var cname: String =""
        var cage: Int = 0
        fun constructor(cname: String, cage: Int){
            this.cage = cage
            this.cname = cname
        }
        fun changeAge(age: Int ?= 0){
//            access to surname or name or age 

        }
    }
}
```

i can't get access to any of the properties from Person1 class

and for instance lets say that we call the class or companion object as bellow:

```
val c1 = Person1.myc.constructor("john",10)
val c2= Person1("jack",20)
```

i can't call the changeAge() function through c1 or c2. the only place where i can use changeAge is through Person1.changeAge() when Person1 has not been instantiated with proper constructor.
i was wondering if there is an alternative for these actions or if there aren't what is the point of having companion objects anyways

Comment: I truly wonder what you _think_ is the point of companion objects. What you're describing is the semantics of member functions of the `Person` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nesting a `class` inside a class [doesn't automatically give you access to an instance of this class, unlike in Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html). The same applies for `object`s, including `companion object`s. `companion` just lets you refer to this object as `Person1` in addition to `Person1.myc`.

Your `fun constructor` isn't a constructor; it's just a method called `constructor`.

Comment: While this answer mentions the reason why it doesn't work, I felt like it doesn't answer the question w.r.t "how to". For others who feel the same check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857824/kotlin-static-methods-and-variables

Answer (score 1):

This is regarding the purpose of companion objects:

I use companion objects to instantiate members which in Java would typically be `static`.

For example, if you have JUnit 4 test and the main service you want to test is static and you want to use the `@BeforeClass` class annotation. This is what you can do:

```
class ExcelDedupReportGeneratorTest {

    companion object {
        init {
            // things that may need to be setup before companion class member variables are instantiated
        }

        // variables you initialize for the class just once:
        var reportGenerator: ExcelReportGenerator? = null

        @BeforeClass @JvmStatic fun setup() {
            val messageSource = Mockito.mock(MessageSource::class.java)
            reportGenerator = ExcelDedupReportGenerator(messageSource)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun whenWrite_ShouldWriteFile() {
        Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("demoReport-dedup.xls")).use {
            reportGenerator?.write(ReportBeanProvider.createReportData(), it)
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the test class accesses the `reportGenerator` element of the companion which exists only once in memory (like a `static` member in Java).