# How to declare Static Variables and Methods in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

How can we define and declare `Static variables` and `static function` in Android while writing code in **kotlin**?

And

Is there any Difference between the `memory allocation of static members` in java vs Kotlin?

Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: have you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352684/what-is-the-equivalent-of-java-static-methods-in-kotlin and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857824/kotlin-static-methods-and-variables/43857895