# Declare static property in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, static-methods, static-block

My `Java` code:

```java
public class Common {
    public static ModelPengguna currentModelPengguna;
}
```

Comment: If you describe your objective we can recommend more idiomatic Kotlin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin static methods and variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43857824/kotlin-static-methods-and-variables)

Answer (score 17):

```
public class Common {
    companion object {
        val currentModelPengguna: ModelPengguna = ModelPengguna()  
    }
}
```

or if the object is static and you want it as Singleton
you can use

```
object Common {
        val currentModelPengguna: ModelPengguna = ModelPengguna()
}
```

a static property in kotlin is introduced by the `companion object` further reading:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects

Answer (score 1):

Java uses the same `static` keyword for many features, like:

- Global variable/ property.
- Constant, like: `private static final String TAG = ...`
- Class's on-load initializer - which Java names Static-block.

While Kotlin separates these.

### Example

**If we have a Java file, like:**

```java
public class MyClass {
    private static final String TAG = "my-tag";

    @NonNull
    public static MyType myVariable = new MyType();

    @Nullable
    public static MyType myNullableVariable = null;

    static {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got this far!");
    }

    public void onSomething() {
        onSomething(false);
    }

    public void onSomething(optionalArg: Boolean) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Then the Kotlin version may look something like:**

```kotlin
open class MyClass {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "my-tag"

        @JvmStatic
        var myVariable: MyType = MyType()

        @JvmStatic
        var myNullableVariable: MyType? = null

        init {
            Log.d(TAG, "Got this far!")
        }
    }

    @JvmOverloads
    open fun onSomething(optionalArg: Boolean = false) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Where:

- Kotlin's `open class` is like Java's `public class`.
- The "`@JvmStatic`" part allows Java to use Kotlin's `myVariable`, as if it were Java's `static` memeber.
- The "`@JvmOverloads`" part allows Java to call Kotlin's `onSomething` without need to pass all parameters.

> **Note** that "`: MyType`" part can be omitted, because both Kotlin and Android-studio IDE do auto-detect the type based on initializer (e.g. based on the " `= MyType()`" part).
>
> Also, `@JvmStatic` and `@JvmOverloads` do NOT need any  import (as they're built-in features of Kotlin).

Answer (score 0):

Static variables declare and initialize in to companion object for example:

```
 public class MyClass {

    companion object{
        const val TAG: String = "my-tag"
        const val myVariable: MyType = MyType()
        var myNullableVariable: MyType? = null
    }
}
```