# Does Kotlin have something like static variable inside a function?

Tags: kotlin

I'm wondering if it has something that works like static variable inside a function in C.

In C language we have this:

```
void next_x()
{
    static int x = 0;
    x++;
}
```

Variable `x` is declared and initialized inside a function. As far I know C  - it can be used only in the scope of this function and it is initialized only in first call of this function.

I need something like this in Kotlin. I have code similar to this:

```
private val x: Int = 0

fun getNextX() : Int {
    x++;
    return x;
}
```

and I would like to have something like this:

```
fun getNextX() : Int {
    static val x: Int = 0 // this is not Kotlin code
    x++;
    return x;
}
```

I want to:

1. Limit `x` variable scope to emphasize that this object is only used by this function and protect it from changes from outside
2. Initialize it only once
3. Keep value/state between function calls

Example above was simplified. In fact I need something like this for ArrayList with limited scope, but retaining state.

I realize that we have singleton pattern which is almost perfect for such needs (except limited scope), but maybe Kotlin offers something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you declare static property in kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514503/how-do-you-declare-static-property-in-kotlin)

Comment: No, Kotlin doesn't feature static local variables. In any case, their usefulness would be somewhat limited because such a function would not be thread-safe.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski No, for two reasons. Reason 1: static variable in C is something diffrent from Java static variable. Reason 2: You cannot declare static variable inside a method in Java.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't anything similar to that in Kotlin, but to simulate a similar effect, you can declare an `object` with all your `static` variables as properties, and put the function body in an `invoke` operator:

```
object NextX {
    private var x = 0
    operator fun invoke() = x++
}
```

You basically create an `object`, but syntactically, it works like a function that you can call:

```
fun main() {
    println(NextX()) // 0
    println(NextX()) // 1
    println(NextX()) // 2
}
```

If you think of the entire `object` as your function, then `x` is indeed only accessible within the "function".

Comment: That's pretty close to my idea. I will experiment with that and see if such thing would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Functions in Kotlin are stateless, so this is not possible out of the box.

You can get creative though, by having an object with a function which returns the function you desire.

```
val foo: () -> Int = object {
  var x = 0
  fun createFunc() = fun() = x++
}.createFunc()

foo() // 0
foo() // 1
```

Note how `x` doesn't even have to be `private`, because the `object` itself cannot be referenced.

This would meet your criteria.